# Alert controller input box validation

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How to validate and show error for Input in Alert Controller in Ionic 2 or 3

```
let prompt = Alert.create({
      title: 'Alert input validation',
      message: "How can I validate below input field?",
      inputs: [ 
        {
          name: 'email',
          placeholder: 'email'
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: data => {
                        let validateObj = this.validateEmail(data);
                        if (!validateObj.isValid) {
                            alert(validateObj.message);
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            //make HTTP call
                        }
                    }
        }
      ]
    });
```

Some one already updated alertcontroller and did pull request for Ionic team. i think Ionic team planning implement this in future.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/12541

I need some work around for this validation feature.

plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/IBonfBJngky0h8UtMwMD?p=preview

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Is opening a new Ionic Alert with the error message a valid option on your end?

Comment: Thanks for reply @sebaferreras its ok for me but after entering valid email address error message should disappear.

Comment: The documentation does mention that if you are looking for a complex form ui then it's better to use a modal instead. This looks like a complex scenario.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

At this moment this feature has not been implemented.You can see [**this Git issue**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/5916).

I have used `Toast` notification here and I didn't get any complaint about it from my client :)

Here is what I have done.

*alert boxe's `done` handler:*

```
{
          text: 'Done',
          handler: (data) => {
            if (EmailValidator.isValid(data.email)) {
              if (this.data) {
                //my code
              } else {
                //my code
              }
              return true;
            } else {
              this.showErrorToast('Invalid Email');
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
```

*Toast method is like this:*

```
showErrorToast(data: any) {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: data,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'top'
    });

    toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
      console.log('Dismissed toast');
    });

    toast.present();
  }
```

*UI*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I will try and let you know.

Comment: OK sure. No problem :)

Answer (score 13):

I did find a work around by using setMessage method. Initially message will be empty and when user has not entered any value the validation message will be filled up on click. Find the code snippet below

```
let prompt = Alert.create({
  title: 'Alert input validation',
  message: '',
  inputs: [ 
    {
      name: 'email',
      placeholder: 'email'
    },
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Save',
      handler: data => {
                    let validateObj = this.validateEmail(data);
                    if (!validateObj.isValid) {
                        prompt.setMessage('Your validation message');
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        //make HTTP call
                    }
                }
    }
  ]
});
```

You can override the font of message in variable.scss file as below

```
$alert-md-message-text-color:red;
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really nice workaround! Thank you! One note: if you set the sass variable like that it will be valid for all alert dialogs in your app and therefore every message of each alert dialog will be red. Am I right? Therefore I added a custom cssClass to the alert dialog.

Comment: I liked how you used the setMessage to give feedback to the user. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

The solution using a toast is completely valid, but from the perspective of UX I find it splits the focus of the user too much to have an open alert and be messaging form errors through toasts.

Instead, I like to append the validations to the DOM of the alert.  This example is a simple alert with a single input, but could be easily extended with some util methods to create the validation boilerplate.  I also created the example in a quick [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v5-tuosd8?file=src/app/app.component.ts). In my case I already include a variant of the validation errors markup throughout the application so the styles are already global, and I just need to introduce the markup to have it styled.

```js
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Example Header',
  subHeader: 'Example Subheader',
  message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.',
  backdropDismiss: false,
  cssClass: 'example-alert',
  inputs: [
    {
      type: 'text',
      name: 'mobilePhone',
      label: 'Mobile Phone',
      placeholder: 'Mobile phone (10 digits)',
      attributes: {
        maxlength: 10
      }
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: (formData: { mobilePhone: string }) => {
        if (formData.mobilePhone && PhoneValidator.isValid(formData.mobilePhone)) 
          return formData;
        } else {
          // Only if no validation has been inserted into the DOM
          if (!alert.getElementsByClassName('validation-errors').length) {
            const input = alert.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

            const validationErrors = document.createElement('div');
            validationErrors.className = 'validation-errors';

            const errorMessage = document.createElement('small');
            errorMessage.classList.add('error-message');
            errorMessage.textContent = 'Invalid phone number';

            validationErrors.appendChild(errorMessage);

            input.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', validationErrors);
          }

          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});

await alert.present();
```

```css
.validation-errors {
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: left;

  .error-message {
    color: var(--ion-color-danger);
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

// Example of markup:
//<div class="validation-errors">
//  <small class="error-message"></small>
//</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate Email by using REGX.

here is sample. just replace this function with yours.

```
validateEmail(data) {
    if( /(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(data.email) ){
      return {
        isValid: true,
        message: ''
      };
    } else {
       return {
          isValid: false,
          message: 'Email address is required'
       }
    }
}
```

i hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a sneaky workaround for this. If you want `input` fields to shake(vibrate) if the input is incorrect or to display an error underneath. You can give this a shot.

I tested this on Ionic 6, but I'm not sure about earlier versions (Feel free to try and update this answer)

Essentially, `alertController` returns a `Ion element` and you can use `querySelector` to locate the `inputs` and add your styles and use [animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) shortcut method.

[@ionic/(vue/angular/react)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert)

```
import { alertController } from '@ionic/(vue/angular/react)'

const showAlert = async () => {
  const alert = await alertController.create({
    header: 'Personal details',
    backdropDismiss: false,
    buttons: [
      {
        text: 'Save',
        handler: (data) => {
          // Do you fields validation here
          let isEmailInvalid = !data.email

          shakeInputs(alert, 'email', isEmailInvalid)
  
          if (isEmailInvalid) {
            return false
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'email',
        placeholder: 'email'
      }
    ]
  })
}

function shakeInputs(alert, placeholder, isInvalid) {
  const input = alert.querySelector(`.alert-wrapper .alert-input-wrapper input[placeholder="${placeholder}"]`)
  if (input) {
    if (isInvalid) {
      input.classList.add('custom-input-error')

      const shake = [
        { offset: 0, transform: 'translateX(0)' },
        { offset: 0.25, transform: 'translateX(5px)' },
        { offset: 0.5, transform: 'translateX(-5px)' },
        { offset: 0.75, transform: 'translateX(5px)' },
        { offset: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)' }
      ]

      input.animate(shake, { duration: 200, iterations: 1 })
    } else {
      input.classList.remove('custom-input-error')
    }
  }
}

<style>
  .custom-input-error {
    border: 2px solid red;

    &::placeholder {
      --ion-placeholder-color: red;
    }
  }
</style>
```

[image]