# How to give validation for alert alert input in ionic?

Tags: forms, angular, ionic-framework

I have add one alert input field to change password,But How can we give validation to input field in ionic?

**account.ts**

```
 changePassword(){
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
   title: 'Change Password',
   buttons: [
    'Cancel']
 });

  alert.addInput({
  name: 'Password',
  value: this.password,
  placeholder: 'password'
  });
 alert.addButton({
    text: 'Ok',
    handler: (data: any) => {
    this.userData.setUsername(data.username);
    let accountData=new FormData();
    accountData.append('userid',this.userid),
    accountData.append('password',data.Password)
    this.works.changePassword(accountData).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res),
      err=>{
        console.log(err)
      }
      })
    }
   });
  alert.present();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alert.setMessage('text')` method to show validation message and don't forgot to add `return false` after validation to prevent alert dismiss.

```
public displayToAlert(title, subTitle) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: title,
      subTitle: subTitle,
      message: '',
      enableBackdropDismiss: false,
      inputs: [
        {name: 'userEmail',
      placeholder: 'Email Id'}
      ],
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: () => {
        }
      },{
        text: 'Send',
        handler: datas => {
          if(datas.userEmail != null && datas.userEmail.length > 0){
            this.onExportNew();
          }else{
            alert.setMessage('<b style="color: red;">Enter valid email id.</b>');
            return false;
          }
        }
      }]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

For Reference : [Alert controller input box validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969821/alert-controller-input-box-validation)